# How to use global variable from inside a function if already have a local variable with same name

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

- Wants to invoke global variable from inside the function instead of a local variable with same name already there;
- I have tried this.

---

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Globalization;
    namespace tesitingInMyKitchen
    {
        class program
        {
           static string cheese = "chedar";

            static void Main()
            {
                string cheese = "swiss";
                //printing local cheese
                Console.WriteLine(cheese);
                //here want to print global cheese 
                Console.WriteLine(global :cheese);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have several concepts mixed up here, global is the root namespace, its only use is to instruct the namespace navigator that you are starting at the root and not relative to the current namespace  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/how-to-use-the-global-namespace-alias ,  there are no global variables as c# is an OO language, the static keyword places the object on the class not the instance see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Answer (score 6):

your "global variable"

```
static string cheese = "chedar";
```

is not a global variable but a static property of the class `program`. You can therefore access it this way:

```
Console.WriteLine(program.cheese);
```

please note that, as you haven't explicitly defined an access modifier (`public`, `protected`, `internal` or `private`) on your static property, access is by default limited to members of the class the property is defined in (implicit `private` declaration), while the class `program` itself is by default decleared `internal`. So this property `cheese` may be available to all methods within your class `program`, but it is not available to any member of any other class, including classes that inherit from `program`.

Comment: Ok , thanks i got this due to global key word in python which is using global variables in functions just by global keyword. But this is not the case in c#.

Answer (score 1):

For static field, use *ClassName.FieldName*, if it's non-static, you could use 'this' keyword: *this.FieldName*

```
class MyClass
{       
    static string cheese = "chedar";
    string cheese1 = "global";

    void Main()
    {
        string cheese = "swiss";
        string cheese1 = "local";

        Console.WriteLine(cheese);
        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.cheese);

        Console.WriteLine(cheese1);
        Console.WriteLine(this.cheese1);
    }
}
```